# Kafka Consumer no exceptions or warnings when broker becomes unavailable

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have set up a number of Kafka consumers using Spring Kafka, which work fine. However, by accident I have just found that when one of the consumer goes down, I don't see any exceptions go to the error log. I am only seeing the following in the catalina.out:

```
2019-04-13 02:07:37.008  INFO 17875 --- [alconDataRiver1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=dataRiver1] Group coordinator xxx-xx2x1-xxx-xxx.xxxxxx.com:38900 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
......
2019-04-13 02:07:38.014  INFO 17875 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=dataRiver1] Error sending fetch request (sessionId=1593042214, epoch=92705) to node 1: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException.
```

I don't know why there are no exceptions thrown in this case.

I am using Spring Boot for my project.

Here is how I set up a consumer:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> fasConsumerFactoryFirst() {

    Map<String, Object> dataRiverProps = getFasDataRiverProps();
    dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("fas1.bootstrap.servers"));
    dataRiverProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, env.getProperty("fas1.schema.registry.url"));
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(dataRiverProps);
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${" + PROP_KAFKA_FAS_TOPICS + "}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = "fasKafkaListenerContainerFactoryFirst")
    public void consumeAvroFirst(List<Message<GenericData.Record>> list) {
        consumeJsonMessageBatch(convertAvroToJsonBatch(list), KAFKA_CONSUMER_FAS_1);
}
```

I wonder if there are any configurations that I have missed that could help generate exceptions (or maybe warnings) in such a case that will be written into the error logs, so that I can easily monitor. Thanks!

Comment: I do see a bit later in the catalina.out the following WARN:
2019-04-13 02:09:28.575  WARN 17875 --- [ntainer#5-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=dataRiver1] Connection to node 2147483646 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Is there a way to redirect this warning into the error log? Thanks!

Comment: If one of the consumer id down you should check for rebalancing message

Comment: I can see the rebalancing message in catalina.out as follows:
2019-04-11 11:22:23.045  INFO 28827 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=dataRiver1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing   
But again, is there a way for me to have it written out to the error log as a warning? Thanks!

Comment: Those are from spring framework, you can implement some custom interceptor that gets involed before rebalancing and write custom logs in it @Hua

Comment: Thanks @Deadpool. Is there an example that you can point me to? Since I am using Spring Kafka, I thought it would be pretty easy to have this configured.

Comment: Just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524315/handle-failure-in-case-the-kafka-broker-is-down.